# transfer value of variable y from method database to method display in java

Tags: java

how to print value of y from method database in method display?
    package libb;
    import java .util.Scanner;

```
public class Libb {
void database()               //first method database
{
Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the number");
int y=x.nextInt();             //value y in database
} 
void display()                //second method display
{
System.out.println("Number is" +y);   //print y in another method ie. display
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

Comment: [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the method and pass variable Y as a parameter.

```
public class Libb {
void database()               //first method database
{
Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the number");
int y=x.nextInt();             //value y in database
///line added here call method and pass y at same time
display(y);
} 
//parameter added here
void display(int y)                //second method display
{
System.out.println("Number is" +y);   //print y in another. 
method ie. display
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

Or you could also use a method return and call the database method in the display method and assign it to a variable as it would be returning a value and use that in your print out .